# Echo there are no posts wp_get_archives

Tags: sidebar, wp-get-archives

I'm using `wp_get_archives` to output my archives in a sidebar - but if there are no posts I would like to `echo` out 'there are no posts to show'. Is there a conditional statement or filter I can use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use `get_archives_link` with same parameters as `wp_get_archives` and either use the output from that to determine if there are no posts or there is a filter in `get_archives_link` called `get_archives_link` that gives you access to the HTML.

Source: http://wpseek.com/function/get_archives_link/